# QMC2- Background Menu music feature?

Tags: mame

I really like QMC2...it is really nice. I see in the wiki that it has a media player. But what I want to do is have a mp3 sample of a some video game loop in the background of the menu selection. Is there a feature for QMC2 to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it....I had to compile qmc2 with the `phonon` option.